# Algorithm behind Matlab griddedInterpolant, Image gray value interpolation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, interpolation

I am now working on the interpolation of gray value for an image. I wanna use the matlab function griddedInterpolant. For the interpolation method it has 'cubic' and 'spline'. Both of them are C2 continues. I have found the algorithm about 'cubic' (actually 'bicubic' since my data are 2D) as listed in WiKipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation.

I wanna ask if some one know the algorithm behind 'spline' (actually 'bicubic spline' for 2D). Because I don't quite understand the difference between them.

And for my calculation I need the gradient of the gray value too. Since in function griddedInterpolant it is not possible to get the coefficients of the interpolation, there's no way to calculate the gradients directly.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: The  'cubic' method should only result in a C1 surface.

Comment: @fang yes, you're right. A little dizzy after long time programming. Thanks.  Then I can understand it.  That is the difference between them.